# How clock signal is distributed in Microprocessor chip?

Tags: microchip, microprocessor

How clock signals are distributed in Microprocessor. I have been searching over the internet but nothing found useful. To complete process certain clock periods are needed 4 or 80 cycles.How signal is driven to the particular mosfet gate.

Answer (score 1):

We use something called an "H-tree" clocking scheme.  I do not have a layout map that I can share for a CPU, but below is the layout map for a FPGA.   If you look for "H-tree", you should find a bunch on information on the technique.

[image: FPGA clock H-TREE]

Comment: The major reason for the use of the H tree is that it equalises the delay to all the logic blocks.

Comment: Can you suggest me a Professional Book for a custom clock signal distribution